# What would be different behaviour and result on different values of page options and their combination in Sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, pre-rendering, client-side-rendering

[Sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) provide 3 page options givent https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options

1. `prerender`
2. `csr`
3. `ssr`

These are the possible cases

1. Taking one at a time
   e.g. where we are setting
   `export const prerender = true;`
   or
   `export const prerender = true;`
   or
   `export const prerender = false;`
   or
   `export const csr = true;`
   or
   `export const csr = false;`
   or
   `export const ssr = true;`
   or
   `export const ssr = false;`
2. Taking two at a time
   `export const prerender = true;` and `export const csr = true;`
   or
   `export const prerender = true;` and `export const csr = false;`
   or
   `export const prerender = false;` and `export const csr = true;`
   or
   `export const prerender = false;` and `export const csr = false;`
   or
   `export const prerender = true;` and `export const ssr = true;`
   or
   `export const prerender = true;` and `export const ssr = false;`
   or
   `export const prerender = false;` and `export const ssr = true;`
   or
   `export const prerender = false;` and `export const ssr = false;`
   ...
   ...
   So many more possibities of combination of value of `ssr` and `csr`
3. Taking three at time
   e.g. So many possiblites of combination of values of `ssr`, `csr` and `prerender`

Out of these so many possiblites some may be non-sensible but some would be sensible.

So what would be different behaviour and results on these various possibities?